# Some Word headings not being converted to bookmarks in PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a word document, a newsletter, with fully defined headings and a working ToC. In the Navigation panel, all of my headings appear correctly nested. However, when I convert it to a pdf, some of my Level 4 headings appear in the bookmarks list while some do not.

I have checked all the outline settings for the styles I'm using (there are only 4). I have inserted style breaks to break up lines in which two styles appear. I began to suspect that it may have been a structural problem; that I have a tree of `Heading 1` - `Heading 4` - `Heading 2` - `Heading 4` - `Heading 4` beneath one another but again, some of the level 4 headings appear in the bookmarks while others do not.

I can see no difference between those which appear and those which don't. Does anyone have suggestions as to what I can do to solve this?

I'm using Office 365 and Acrobat DC Pro on Windows 7

Update: I have checked all the headings to make sure that they are indeed Headings. I have tried removing and retyping the text to check for strange things which may have been copied in. No change.

Update 2: Cutting the whole section, pasting back as text only and reapplying heading styles seems to have done the trick. At least on one of the misbehaving headings. Thanks @Albin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refusing to convert to normal seems to be an indication that word doesn't handle the format properly. I had similar problems in the past. It "seem" to have s.th. do do with "non visible characters" like line breaks being included in the format.

What solved it for me, was to deleted (copy and delete of course) the whole "section" including a few lines above and below it to make so that all traces of the format are deleted. Then put it back by pasting "text only" then reapplying the format. So far this always worked for me.

If you're unsure "cut" into the previous and next paragraph (where the text format works correctly) this way you make sure you remove all the "faulty" formatting. But it's a little bit more work to reapply the format.